# Prove that $E \cap A^c$ is non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis

> $E \subset \mathscr{R}$ is non-measurable set. Prove that if $A \subset \mathscr{R}$ is set with measure 0, then set $E \cap A^{c}$ is non-measurable.

Things I know:
if $\mu^*(A)=0$ then $A$ is measurable. $A^c$ is also measurable.
(*) Every set with positive outer measure has a non-measurable subset. This non-measurable subset has as measurable subsets only sets with measure $0$.

Attempt of proof:

1. $A \cap E = \emptyset$ then $E \cap A^{c}=E$ so it's non-measurable set
2. $A \cap E \neq \emptyset$, $E \cap A^c \subset E$ It's a subset of non-measurable set, so it can be measurable or non-measurable. If I show that $\mu^*(E \cap A^c) \neq 0$ that means $E \cap A^c$ is non-measurable (using (*)). But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that we are dealing with Lebesgue measure on the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, or some other [complete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure).  The things you say "I know" seem to depend on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E=(E\setminus A)\cup (E\cap A)$. Since $E\cap A\subseteq A$, $\mu^*(E\cap A)\le\mu^*(A)=0$. It follows that $\mu^*(E\cap A)=0$ and, therefore $E\cap A$ is measurable. If $E\setminus A$ were measurable as well, then $E$ would be union of two measurable sets.